# Add noise to the frame using Polar Method in C

Tags: c, video, encoding, frame, yuv

i wrote a program who can read the Original YUV-file and add Gaussian noise with mean 0 to the Modified one.
the problem is that i don't know how to implement the Polar function on the main function, when i tried its always generate errors.
anyone have any ideas to solve my problem.
thanks

```
void polar(double *x1, double *x2)
{
   double u, v, q, p;

   do {
      u = 2.0 * random() - 1;
      v = 2.0 * random() - 1;
      q  = u * u + v * v;
   } while (q >= 1.0 || q == 0.0);

   p = sqrt(-2 * log(q) / q);
   *x1 = u * p;
   *x2 = v * p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int a;
    double a1,a2;
    fp1= fopen("FOOTBALL_352x288_30_orig_01.yuv","rb");
    fp2= fopen("FOOTBALL_352x288_30_orig_02.yuv","wb");


    int tab[10]="";

    while(!feof(fp1))
    {
        fread(tab,sizeof(int),1,fp1);
        fwrite(tab,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
    }      

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not calling `polar` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Currently you copy OOTBALL_352x288_30_orig_01.yuv into FOOTBALL_352x288_30_orig_02.yuv supposing the input file contains binary representation of _int_). I encourage you to not use _feof_ but to check the result of `fread`

Comment: the problem is that i don't know where and how i call the `polar` code

Comment: The problem is we cannot know what you want to do and what the file contains. Note also you read _int_ (from binary) and _polar_ uses _float_

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to read in frames from a YUV video sequence
and add noise to the frame (Gaussian noise with mean 0).Using YUV sequences from
ftp://ftp.tnt.uni-hannover.de/pub/svc/testsequences/
FOOTBALL_352x288_30_orig_01_yuv (352x288 pixels, 30Hz frame rate, 4:2:0)

Comment: Visibly the format is not a sequence of 3 integers in binary, you cannot read the file like that

Answer (score -1):

The *polar* function expects the address of two doubles as inputs. If you declared *a1* and *a2* to be passed into polar, you can call *polar(&a1, &a2)*. The *polar* function will have set the *a1* and *a2* by the time it returns. To check this, try printing these variables before and after your call to the *polar* function.

Comment: the problem is not here ^^

Comment: From the question: "the problem is that i don't know how to implement the Polar function on the main function". This answer describes how to call the polar function from the main function.

Comment: You do not understand, the OP doesn't know how to read the YUV file, you say _give floats address_, you don't say from where/how these floats come from

Comment: Where these variables come from is irrelevant as long as they are properly allocated (which they are since they reside on the frame of main). The polar function does not use or care about the initial value of the doubles. It will overwrite these values regardless.